# jquery Window Height getting same when Load and After Resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, window

I am trying to adjust my div height based on browser window height. but i am getting same height when page/body being load and after resize the  browser window.

```
function setDivHeight() {
    var bodyheight = $(document).height();
    document.getElementById('divName').style.height = (bodyheight - 180) + "px";
}

function pageLoad() {
    setDivHeight();
}

window.onresize = setDivHeight();
```

Comment: Where's the rest of the code?

Comment: `window.onresize = setDIVheight;`  _no parenthesis_  and `$("#divName").height(bodyheight - 180)`

Answer (score 1):

```
// Returns height of browser viewport
// Use this
$( window ).height();

// Returns height of HTML document
$( document ).height();
```

Example from: http://api.jquery.com/height/

Answer (score 0):

for height you can use

```
$( window ).height();
```

you want body height

`$("body").height();`

Answer (score 0):

When you use jQuery, use it to the fullest. Mixing it with plain JS would only increase the number of lines of code. Your code may be re-written as the following.

```
function setDivHeight() {
    //height of HTML document
    var documentHeight = $(document).height();
    //height of browser viewport
    var viewportHeight = $(window).height();
    $('#divName').height(documentHeight - 180); // OR viewportHeight - 180 as appropriate
}

// = onload and onresize
$(window).on("load resize", setDivHeight);
```